# How do I rotate an image overlay inside of a drawn polygon

Tags: objective-c

I am making an app with an overlay on a map kit, I am overlaying a picture onto the map to make the picture a map. I have drawn a polygon to border the place where I want the picture, it works but I used the code and filled the polygon with a uicolor but instead of a color a picture, the picture seems to only come out one way and I cannot figure out how to rotate the fill picture. Please help

```
 MKPolygonView *polyView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
polyView.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
polyView.fillColor = [UIColor  colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Campus-map-labels.jpg"]];
```

Comment: please do show the code so we can help

Comment: @rockinfresh heres the code i used to do this (i am a beginner coder so I'm not that good at this and am just learning) ` MKPolygonView *polyView = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    polyView.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    polyView.fillColor = [UIColor  colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Campus-map-labels.jpg"]];`

Comment: This doesn't look like C++. Objective C perhaps?

Comment: yes this is Objective C i was thinking of something else when writing this, sorry @Thomas